# What is the difference between LOAD_DEFAULT and LOAD_NORMAL for WebSettings?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an activity with a WebView and want to cache content.  By default, it does not appear to be using the cache.

Android's [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) has several different cache-related constants.

When I set the cache mode to 'LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK', it appears to use the cache.  However, I don't want to use expired cache content.

This leaves me with using:

1. LOAD_DEFAULT: "Default cache usage pattern" or
2. LOAD_NORMAL: "Normal cache usage pattern"

But the documentation does not elaborate on what "normal" and "default" mean.

How do these two modes differ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, one would expect that NORMAL_MODE is the default mode, but clearly this is two different values.

I think answer to question 2. (LOAD_NORMAL) is answered in the [documentation for  WebSettings.setCacheMode(int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode%28int%29)

> For a normal page load, the cache is checked and content is re-validated as needed. When navigating back, content is not revalidated, instead the content is just pulled from the cache. This function allows the client to override this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_NORMAL), `LOAD_DEFAULT` and `LOAD_NORMAL` do the same thing now:

```
public static final int LOAD_NORMAL

Added in API level 1
This constant was deprecated in API level 17.
This value is obsolete, as from API level HONEYCOMB and onwards it has the same effect as LOAD_DEFAULT.
```

Answer (score 0):

Now they are [the same](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_NORMAL).

> LOAD_NORMAL
>
> This constant was deprecated in API level 17. This value is obsolete, as from API level HONEYCOMB and onwards it has the **same effect** as LOAD_DEFAULT.